# A system for determination of human language from input text:: robustification

Tags: java, natural-language-processing

This program works, but it's pretty clunky and fragile. I want to make it more dynamic / solid.

For instance some of the functionality depends on the order I entered things into an `ArrayList`, that seems to me to be an example of a terribly odious smelly code.

```
//These structures hold the word list & corresponding flag indicator for each language
static HashMap<String, Boolean>  de_map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
static HashMap<String, Boolean>  fr_map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
static HashMap<String, Boolean>  ru_map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
static HashMap<String, Boolean> eng_map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();


public static void main( String[] args ) throws URISyntaxException, IOException
{
    //put them all in a list for later processing
    List<HashMap<String, Boolean>> lang_maps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Boolean>>();

    lang_maps.add( de_map );
    lang_maps.add( fr_map );
    lang_maps.add( ru_map );
    lang_maps.add( eng_map );



    //this holds all the dictionary files, i.e. word lists garners from language folders
    ArrayList<Path> dictionary_files = new ArrayList<Path>();


    //THIS SEGMENT IS FOR DYNAMICALLY LOCATING THE DIRECTORY, SO THE PROGRAM WORKS "OUT OF THE BOX"
/*******************************************************************************************************************************************/
    File currentDir = new File( "." ); // Read current file location
    //System.out.println(currentDir.getAbsolutePath());

    File targetDir = null;
    if (currentDir.isDirectory()) 
    {
        targetDir = new File( currentDir, "word_lists_1" ); // Construct the target directory file with the right parent directory
    }
    if ( targetDir != null && targetDir.exists() )
    {
        SearchDirectories.listDirectoryAndFiles( targetDir.toPath(), dictionary_files );
    }
/*******************************************************************************************************************************************/

    //this populates word presence data structs for each language
    for(Path dir : dictionary_files)
    {

        String word_holding_directory_path = dir.toString().toLowerCase();


        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( dir.toString() ) );
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            //System.out.println(line);
            if(word_holding_directory_path.toLowerCase().contains("/de/") )
            {
                de_map.put(line, false);    
            }
            if(word_holding_directory_path.toLowerCase().contains("/ru/") )
            {
                ru_map.put(line, false);
            }
            if(word_holding_directory_path.toLowerCase().contains("/fr/") )
            {
                fr_map.put(line, false);
            }
            if(word_holding_directory_path.toLowerCase().contains("/eng/") )
            {
                eng_map.put(line, false);
            }
        }
    }


    //print debugging
//        for (Map.Entry entry : de_map.entrySet()) 
//        {
//            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ", " + entry.getValue());
//        }


/*******************************************************************************************************************************************/ 
    //GET THE USER INPUT
    ArrayList<String> input_text = new ArrayList<String>();

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a sentence: ");

    String [] tokens = in.nextLine().split("\\s");

    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
    {
        input_text.add( tokens[i].toString() );
    }
/*******************************************************************************************************************************************/

    //iterate over the hashmaps of all the languages we're considering
    //and flip the bool if there is a hit
    for( int i = 0; i < lang_maps.size(); i++ )
    {
        HashMap<String, Boolean> working_lang_map = lang_maps.get( i );

        Iterator it = working_lang_map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) 
        {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            //System.out.println(pair.getKey() + ", " + pair.getValue());

            for(String word : input_text)
            {
                if(pair.getKey().toString().toLowerCase().trim().equals( word.toLowerCase().trim() ) )
                {
                    working_lang_map.put(pair.getKey().toString(), true);
                }
            }          
        }

    }

    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    // this is fragile. since it depends on order. need to make it 
    // more robust
    int total_de  = 0;
    int total_fr  = 0;
    int total_ru  = 0;
    int total_eng = 0;

    //iterate over all the hashmaps and count the hit totals
    for( int i = 0; i < lang_maps.size(); i++ )
    {
        HashMap<String, Boolean> working_lang_map = lang_maps.get( i );

        //System.out.println( working_lang_map );

        for (Map.Entry entry : working_lang_map.entrySet()) 
        {
            if( ((Boolean) entry.getValue()) == true )
            {
                //this part is really stupid
                if( i == 0)
                {
                    total_de++;
                }
                if( i == 1)
                {
                    total_fr++;
                }
                if( i == 2)
                {
                    total_ru++;
                }
                if( i == 3)
                {
                    total_eng++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    HashMap< String, Integer > most_hits_lang = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    most_hits_lang.put( "German", total_de );
    most_hits_lang.put( "French", total_fr );
    most_hits_lang.put( "Russian", total_ru );
    most_hits_lang.put( "English", total_eng );


    Entry<String,Integer> maxEntry = null;

    for(Entry<String,Integer> entry : most_hits_lang.entrySet()) 
    {
        if (maxEntry == null || entry.getValue() > maxEntry.getValue()) 
        {
            maxEntry = entry;
        }
    }

    System.out.println( maxEntry.getKey() );
}
```

The full code and everything necessary to run it can be found [on my GitHub page](https://github.com/h1395010/language_detective/tree/69ccd0b6cc040013b267a75a6aee862130665740/src).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right about the clunky and fragile.
A lot of improvements are possible.
Most notably,
many unnecessary elements can be rewritten simpler, shorter, cleaner.
Let's go from the top.

#### Prefer interface types instead of implementation

Instead of this:

> ```
> static HashMap<String, Boolean>  de_map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
> ```

If you don't have a specific need for a `HashMap`, declare as a `Map`:

```
static Map<String, Boolean>  de_map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
```

Do this everywhere.

#### `Map<String, Boolean>` or `Set<String>`

Maps with boolean as value type are always suspicious.
Very often they can be rewritten as `Set<>` instead.
We'll get to that too a bit later.

#### Use the diamond operator

Instead of:

> ```
> static Map<String, Boolean>  fr_map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
> ```

Use the modern diamond operator:

```
static Map<String, Boolean>  fr_map = new HashMap<>();
```

This is supported as of Java 7, which is the lowest officially supported Java version. Consider migrating to it ASAP.

Another similar example, instead of this:

> ```
>     List<HashMap<String, Boolean>> lang_maps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Boolean>>();
> ```

Should be:

```
    List<Map<String, Boolean>> lang_maps = new ArrayList<>();
```

#### Don't throw exceptions in vain

The `main` method is declared to throw `URISyntaxException`,
but I don't see where that can come from.
Perhaps from `SearchDirectories.listDirectoryAndFiles` ?
I doubt you really need it.

Perhaps related to this (or perhaps not at all) is that `SearchDirectories.listDirectoryAndFiles` takes a `Path` as parameter.
I'm wondering if that's necessary at all.
Can't you rewrite it with a simple `File` ?

#### Unnecessary stuff

Instead of this:

> ```
>     File currentDir = new File( "." ); // Read current file location
>
>     File targetDir = null;
>     if (currentDir.isDirectory()) 
>     {
>         targetDir = new File( currentDir, "word_lists_1" ); // Construct the target directory file with the right parent directory
>     }
>     if ( targetDir != null && targetDir.exists() )
>     {
>         // ...
>     }
> ```

This is exactly the same:

```
    File currentDir = new File(".");

    targetDir = new File(currentDir, "word_lists_1"); 

    if (targetDir.exists()) {
        // ...
    }
```

Simpler isn't it? I also removed the redundant comments,
and changed the formatting to the style used by major IDEs.
Speaking of comments,
putting comments at the end of lines is not a great idea,
as it makes the lines longer,
and forces the reader to scroll horizontally to the far right.

#### `if` or `if-else` ?

About this code:

> ```
>             if (word_holding_directory_path.toLowerCase().contains("/de/")) {
>                 de_map.put(line, false);
>             }
>             if (word_holding_directory_path.toLowerCase().contains("/ru/")) {
>                 ru_map.put(line, false);
>             }
>             if (word_holding_directory_path.toLowerCase().contains("/fr/")) {
>                 fr_map.put(line, false);
>             }
>             if (word_holding_directory_path.toLowerCase().contains("/eng/")) {
>                 eng_map.put(line, false);
>             }
> ```

Can you have paths like `something/fr/.../eng/.../de/`?
I suspect that a path will only contain either "fr", "eng", "de", and so on.
In which case these conditions should be chained with `else-if`.

Also,
instead of evaluating `word_holding_directory_path.toLowerCase()`
multiple times,
it would be better to evaluate it only once.

Even worse,
there's really no need to re-evaluate any of these conditions for each `line` of input.
This would be better:

```
        Map<String, Boolean> map;
        if (word_holding_directory_path.toLowerCase().contains("/de/")) {
            map = de_map;
        } else if (word_holding_directory_path.toLowerCase().contains("/ru/")) {
            map = ru_map;
        } else if (word_holding_directory_path.toLowerCase().contains("/fr/")) {
            map = fr_map;
        } else if (word_holding_directory_path.toLowerCase().contains("/eng/")) {
            map = eng_map;
        } else {
            continue;
        }

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            map.put(line, false);
        }
```

#### Unnecessary stuff 2

Instead of this:

> ```
>     ArrayList<String> input_text = new ArrayList<String>();
>     String [] tokens = in.nextLine().split("\\s");
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
>     {
>         input_text.add( tokens[i].toString() );
>     }
> ```

This is exactly the same:

```
    List<String> input_text = Arrays.asList(in.nextLine().split("\\s"));
```

But actually,
you don't need a `List<String>` at all later in your code.
So you could as well just replace the above with:

```
String[] input_text = in.nextLine().split("\\s");
```

And the rest of the code will work the same way.

#### Unnecessary stuff 3

The nested loop after the you get the user input can be simplified using enhanced for-each loops, dropping unnecessary `toString` calls,
and written better as:

```
    for (Map<String, Boolean> working_lang_map : lang_maps) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry : working_lang_map.entrySet()) {
            for (String word : input_text) {
                if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().trim().equals(word.toLowerCase().trim())) {
                    working_lang_map.put(entry.getKey(), true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

... but ... something's awfully wrong here.
Iterating over entries of a map to check if it contains some elements is not normal. Maps are designed for fast access by key, and you're squandering that away.

If you rewrote the maps to contain trimmed and lowercased strings (it seems you can, the rest of the code will work just the same),
then you could simplify the above nested loop and make it more efficient like this:

```
    for (Map<String, Boolean> working_lang_map : lang_maps) {
        for (String word : input_text) {
            String normalized = word.trim().toLowerCase();
            if (working_lang_map.containsKey(normalized)) {
                working_lang_map.put(normalized, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

#### Simplified implementation

I suggest to replace `de_map`, `eng_map`, and the others with `Set<String>` of words, so that you populate:

```
Set<String> enWords = new HashSet<String>();
Set<String> frWords = new HashSet<String>();
Set<String> ruWords = new HashSet<String>();
Set<String> deWords = new HashSet<String>();
```

And a map of languages:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> langMaps = new HashMap<>();
langMaps.put("English", enWords);
langMaps.put("French", frWords);
langMaps.put("Russian", ruWords);
langMaps.put("German", deWords);
```

And then,
instead of setting flags and then counting them,
you can count directly,
replacing the final fragile part with this simpler and more robust approach:

```
    int maxCount = 0;
    String maxLang = null;

    for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : langMaps.entrySet()) {
        int count = 0;
        Set<String> words = entry.getValue();

        for (String word : input_text) {
            String normalized = word.trim().toLowerCase();
            if (words.contains(normalized)) {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        if (count > maxCount) {
            maxLang = entry.getKey();

            maxCount = count;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(maxLang);
```

Comment: that was really awesome man, thank you. I wonder, if perhaps you might consider [this unrelated issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317435/enforce-standardization-of-encoding-for-user-input-file-reader-input) which I've been having with that code.